How do I access the browser clipboard with Playwright/C#/SpecFlow/Reqnroll?
I try to give access browser to clipboard.
I found this https://playwrightsolutions.com/how-do-i-access-the-browser-clipboard-with-playwright/
but it's for playwright with typescrip, so I'm looking for working method for Playwright/C#/SpecFlow/Reqnroll
I tried add "argumentsList.Add("clipboard-read"); to configuration but it doesn't work
        argumentsList.Add("--start-maximized");
        argumentsList.Add("clipboard-read");


I found solution in documentation https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/api/class-browsercontext
var context = await browser.NewContextAsync();
await context.GrantPermissionsAsync(new[] { "clipboard-read" });
// Alternatively, you can use the helper class ContextPermissions
//  to specify the permissions...
// do stuff ...
await context.ClearPermissionsAsync();

